# How to merge arrays in one variable in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

A variable called $result

When  `print_r ($result);`
It goes:

```
Array
(
    [0] => iPhone
)
Array
(
    [0] => iOS
)
Array
(
    [0] => Safari
)
```

Seems like there are 3 Arrays in this $result, but I want to marge it to one and give theme order, I've tried array_merge(), and array_combine(), but none of theme get the result I want, what I really want is:

> Array( 'iPhone', 'iOS', 'Safari' )

So I could output one of them using $results[0] or $results[1]...

How can I achieve that? Thanks alot.

Comment: Use `array_merge()` function [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Comment: I've tried array_merge($result), but this function requires at lest 2 variable, it did't work at this point.

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1320156/8398549) in the duplicate, it [works](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/4c626a03fb0a8f2eb59deb219360b901649fb920) for your case.

Comment: try this one `$result = array_merge(...$result);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `array_merge` with `...` splat operator

```
 $result = array_merge(...$array);
```

OR

```
 $result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', array($a));
```

For example :- https://3v4l.org/38Q5h

Comment: $names = explode(' ', $name);
    $result = array_merge(...$names);
    var_dump($result);
 
Thanks Rakesh, I tried your way like above, but get the warning:
 :  array_merge(): Expected parameter 1 to be an array, string given in ..on line..
But the $names is an Array for sure. How weird is that.

Comment: @Duke check the link mentioned after the answer.

Comment: Thank you, still get the warnings and I will double check my code and your example, thanks very much!

Comment: @Duke i have mentioned the other solution if you have older version of php

Comment: I've tried your second solution, but it returns : 

array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "iPhone"
}
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(3) "iOS"
}
 array(1) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "Safari"
}

 LOL, I think my $array must have some bugs in it, maybe it is not a string before I explode it? I will dig about that. My php version is 7.3, should not be the version problem. Thanks again!

Comment: I’m a fool... the reason why it always got 3 arrays is I was coding inside a “foreach”, when I go outside, everything works perfect, both of your ways works well, thank you for helping me!